# google transcription model "command_and_search" is this enhanced model?

Tags: speech-recognition, google-translation-api, google-speech-to-text-api, transcription

Does anybody know if google transcription model command_and_search is an enhanced model ?

in the documentation https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/transcription-model
I could only find that phone_call and video are enhanced.. There is no information about "command_and_search"

Answer (score 0):

**Command_and_search** model **cannot be used as an Enhanced model** because Enhanced models transcribe audio with higher frequency ranges and larger audio files.

**command_and_search model** :  This model is best for short or single-word utterances like voice commands or voice search.

**Example-** “ok google” , “find me a cafe” , “weather”